# struts 2 : use multiple message resources on jsp

Tags: struts2, internationalization

I need to use multiple resource files on my jsp to show localised messages.
Whats the way to include it in struts 2.

I have seen `<s:i18n name="">`, but this will make the code pretty messy as it need to be written and closed for each of the labels.

I beleive there is message- resource tag in struts 1x which we can declare in struts config.
But in struts 2 its not getting recognised.

Any thing similar on the lines to include it on the top of jsp and to use it later ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In struts.properties, reference your resource files:

```
struts.locale=xx_XX
struts.custom.i18n.resources=global-errors, global-messages, ...
```

Make sure to put your resource files on the classpath and postfix the files with your locale (ie. global-errors_ xx _ XX.properties).

Then, in your JSP you can use the s:text-tag:

Example:

```
<s:text name="your.property"></s:text>
```

If you want to replace params in you property:

```
<s:text name="your.property">
<s:param name="value" value="%{something} />
</s:text>
```

If you need to use a different locale (translate your app), change the locale and add another resourece file postfixed with the new locale.